# MVC6 : UseDeveloperExceptionPage not working from exception thrown in controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, error-handling

I'm trying to implement `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` in my `Startup.Configure`, but the error page does not show if I throw an exception in my controller (but if I instead throw the exception from within the Configure method in Startup.cs, then I get the expected view, see beneath image.

[image]

My `Startup`'s `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("es-ES") };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-AU"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions() { SourceCodeLineCount = 10 });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    // TEST
    // app.Run(context => { throw new Exception("error xxxx"); });   
   

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "areas",
                 pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What you mean don't show "the error page does not show if I throw an exception in my controller"? If you throw the exception inside the controller what will happened?

Comment: The DeveloperExceptionPage does not show / display.

Comment: Can you help us @BrandoZhang ? :)